# iPhoneXでUICollectionViewがずれてしまいます。

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, iphone-x

お世話になります。

Objective-CでUICollectionViewを実装しています。
このUICollectionViewは画面一杯に表示し、左右にスクロールするように実装しました。
（カレンダーを実装しているところです。）

この実装はiPhone5sやiPhone8では正常に描画されるのですが、iPhoneXだと、少し上にずれてしまい、NavigationBarにもぐりこんでしまいます。

このような事象に対する対応方法がわからず困っております。
お手数をお掛け致しますが、対応方法が御座いましたらご教示頂けますでしょうか。

以下が、対象のUICollectionViewのソースコード（一部抜粋）となります。

```
#import "Sample.h"
#import "CalendarCell.h"

@interface Sample ()<UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate> {
    // カレンダーのViewを表示するコレクションView
    UICollectionView *coll;
}

@end

@implementation Sample


- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self setUi];
}

- (void)setUi {
    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] init];
    view.frame = CGRectMake(0, [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarFrame.size.height + self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height);
    [self.view addSubview:view];

    UICollectionViewFlowLayout* flowLayout = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
    flowLayout.itemSize = CGSizeMake([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height);
    [flowLayout setScrollDirection:UICollectionViewScrollDirectionHorizontal];

    coll = [[UICollectionView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height) collectionViewLayout:flowLayout];
    coll.backgroundColor = VIEW_BACK_COLOR;
    coll.pagingEnabled = true;
    [coll setShowsVerticalScrollIndicator:false];
    [coll setShowsHorizontalScrollIndicator:false];
    [view addSubview:coll];

    [coll registerClass:[CalendarCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cell"];

    coll.delegate = self;
    coll.dataSource = self;
}

#pragma mark - UICollectionViewDataSource and UICollectionViewDelegate

-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView {
    return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 12;
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CalendarCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    return cell;
}

- (CGFloat)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 0.0f;
}

- (CGFloat)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout minimumLineSpacingForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 0.0f;
}

@end
```

Comment: CGRectMake(0, ステータスバーの高さ + ナビゲーションバーの高さ, 画面の横幅, 画面の縦幅) の部分は実際にはどのように指定してますか？

Comment: 定数で指定しているなら、iPhone 8 と iPhone X ではステータスバーの高さが違うので当然そうなります。また、ステータスバーの高さは状況（端末の向きや電話の着信中など）でも変わります。そういう個々の状況に個別に対応するのは大変なので、現在はAuto Layoutを使ってレイアウトを決めるのが一般的なやり方となっています。

Comment: コメントありがとう御座います。対象箇所を追記させて頂きました。

Comment: 記載のコードを（CalendarCellなど一部置き換えて）実行してみましたが、ナビゲーションバーの下に潜り込んだりはしないですね。
その代り、コレクションビューの下側は画面からはみ出してしまっています。
あと、これは別の問題ですがViewの構築はviewWillAppearじゃなくてViewDidLoadでやったほうがいいですよ。
このViewControllerから別のVCを表示して、また戻ってきたりするとviewWillAppearは2度目の呼び出しが発生し、2つ目のコレクションビューが追加されてしまいます。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

みなさま、様々なご意見有難う御座いました！
色々と試した結果、以下を追加することで潜り込まなくなりました！！

```
if (@available(iOS 11.0, *)) {
    coll.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = UIScrollViewContentInsetAdjustmentNever;
}
```